# How to get start with Volley in Android?

Tags: android

I watched the google io ,and saw volley. But I don't know how to get start with it.
I've tried  to clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley , but the test project keep warn me "resource directory does not exist" .

please give me some clue!

Comment: [check this url](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android/) to start with volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278866/android-volley-quickstart/17278867#17278867) to get start with.

I write this Test Project , and import com.android.volley and com.android.volley.toolbox from the volley library. And it works ^_^

```
protected static final String TAG = "com.gyh.myvolleytest";
public static final String url = "http://192.168.1.108:8080/httptest/servlet/mainservlet?name=stack&age=23";
public static Response.ErrorListener createErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    };
}

public static Response.Listener<String> createSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // TODO parse response
            String string = response.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "string :" + string);
        }
    };
}

public static Response.Listener<JSONObject> createJsonListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String jsonStr = response.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "jsonStr :" + jsonStr);
            System.out.println(jsonStr);

        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void click(View view) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    // url, null, createJsonListener(), createErrorListener());
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            createSuccessListener(), createErrorListener());
    queue.add(request);
    queue.start();
}
```

Hope this can help ^_^

Answer (score 6):

Set up the project as a library ( Project->Properties->Android->"Is Library" ).
Then, just create the res folder in Volley project, and eclipse will build the Volley.jar !